# Print the last value of a counter before it is updated

Tags: counters

I'd like to print the last update of a counter before it is updated.

For example:

```
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\step}{\stepcounter{num}Step \thenum}

There are \thenum steps:

\step
\step
\step
```

Here the counter "num" is 3, however it is not updated at the beginning.

Is there a way to do this correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Counters start at zero so you should get a 1 from the first step. Is this what you are wondering about?

Comment: Thanks for comment @Schrödinger'scat, no, what I want is to print the last value of the counter at the beginning of the document. The Werner's answer solved my question. Cheers!

Comment: I just tried to find out what the question is. Any, it got closed. I think it might have been a bit more useful if Werner would also have helped to clarify the question. It is generally much harder to make sure that the quality of answers is good if a question is closed.... but if you got what you want everything is good.;-)

Comment: Many thanks @Schrödinger'scat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`totalcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/totalcount) (there are similar packages available):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{totalcount}

\newcounter{num}
\DeclareTotalCounter{num}% Defines \totalnums
\newcommand{\step}{\stepcounter{num}Step \thenum}

\begin{document}

There are \totalnums\ steps:

\step \par
\step \par
\step

\end{document}
```